# In emacs org mode Latex, tyring to use % but I got \%

Tags: latex, escaping, org-mode

I am trying create a latex document from org mode,
and want to use % for comment out line, and {} for grouping,
but org-mode output is % , { }.
How can I output without "" escape character ?

I have attached an image because I am losing format.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to type explicit LaTeX in your org file and have it exported as such, you need to tell org that the text is LaTeX. The easiest way would be

```
#+begin_export latex
% commented line
{\Large Sample text}
#+end_export
```

but you may wish to think about why you are explicitly writing LaTeX in an org file in the first place and that maybe you can achieve your desired outcome with org directly?